# Automatically next step by step tab after the work progress bar was complete

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 3 step by step tabs. After opening the second tab, the progress bar is activated. Necessary to do, after the progress bar must reached the end, tab must automatically transferred to the third tab (the last one). How could this be realized? I would be very grateful for the corrected code. I do not understand js.

```js
$('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#myModal')
    .show(0)
    .find('.modal-bodies > .modal-body')
      .eq(0)
      .addClass('is-showing');
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('#myModal')
    .hide(0)
    .find('.modal-bodies > .modal-body')
    .removeClass('is-showing');
});

$('#myModal .button').on('click', function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.modal-body');

  if( parent.is(':last-child') ) {
    
    return false;
  }

  parent
    .removeClass('is-showing')
    .next('.modal-body')
    .addClass('is-showing');
});


function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 100);
  if (al == 100) {
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
 
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.modal-content{

}


.st-btn{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.modal{
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


.close{
padding: 5px 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
}


.button{
padding: 5px 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #019CDE;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 10px;
}


.text-center{
text-align: center;
}


.modal-wrap{

}


.modal-bodies{
position: relative;
}


.modal-body{
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
display: none;
}


.modal-body.is-showing{
  display: block;
}


.text-confirm{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


.description-confirm{
  font-size: 15px;
}


.accept-confirm{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


.accept-text{
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
}


#loading{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ff6a00;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: round 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes round{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}


.loading-text{
  color: #fff;
}


.loading-modal{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}


.loading-circle{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 50px;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
}

progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-En">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <button id="myBtn" class="st-btn">Start</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">  
   <div class="modal-wrap">
     <div class="modal-bodies">
       <div class="modal-body modal-body-step-1 is-showing">
          <div class="text-confirm">Confirm<br><a class="description-confirm">Please confirm.</a></div>
          <form>
            <div class="text-center">
             <button class="close">Cancel</button>
             <div class="button" onclick='start(0)'>Confirm</div>
            </div>
          </form>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body modal-body-step-2">
     <div class="loading-modal">
         <div class="loading-circle" id="loading"></div>
         <div class="loading-text" id="finalMessage">Proccessing request...</div>
      <progress class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
     
     </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body modal-body-step-3">
        <div class="text-center">
           <button>Verify Now</button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet, and show us what have you already tried?

Comment: Already added  s

Answer (score 0):

I took the script from this - https://jsfiddle.net/32rL6gxk/ and modified somewhat to your needs. Hope this helps..

```
    <div id="sampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="visible-xs">&times;</span>

                    </button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myTitle">Modal Title</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="step1"> <span>Do something for Step 1</span>
                                    <div class="text-confirm">Confirm<br><a class="description-confirm">Please confirm.</a></div>
                                    <form>
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                    <button class="close">Cancel</button>
                                                    <div class="button" id="btnEndStep1">Confirm</div>
                                            </div>
                                    </form>
                        <button id="btnEndStep1" style="visibility: hidden;">NEXT STEP</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="step2" class="hideMe"> <span>Now select something for Step 2</span>

                        <div class="loading-circle" id="loading"></div>
                                                <div class="loading-text" id="finalMessage">Processing request...</div>
                                                    <progress class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>


                                                    <button id="btnEndStep2" style="visibility:hidden;">NEXT STEP</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="step3" class="hideMe"> <span>Finally, type something for Step 3</span>
                        <button id="btnEndStep3">Verify</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="showModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sampleModal">Open The Modal</button>


         <style>


        *{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }



        .st-btn{
          font-size: 50px;
        }

        .modal{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;

        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        }


        .close{
        padding: 5px 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        }


        .button{
        padding: 5px 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #019CDE;
        color: #fff;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 10px;
        }


        .text-center{
        text-align: center;
        }

        .text-confirm{
          font-size: 25px;
          text-align: center;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
        }


        .description-confirm{
          font-size: 15px;
        }


        .accept-confirm{
          height: 50px;
          width: 300px;
          margin-left: 10px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }


        .accept-text{
          padding-top: 5px;
          color: #000;
        }


        #loading{
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          border: 5px solid #ccc;
          border-top-color: #ff6a00;
          border-radius: 100%;
          animation: round 2s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes round{
          from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
          to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }


        .loading-text{
          color: #fff;
        }


        .loading-modal{
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 80px;
        }


        .loading-circle{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        }

        progress[value] {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
           appearance: none;

          width: 250px;
          height: 20px;
        }

        .hideMe {
            display: none;
        }
        #sampleModal{
         z-index: 9999
        }
         </style>

           <script>

    $("#btnEndStep1").click(function () {
        $("#step1").addClass('hideMe');
        $("#step2").removeClass('hideMe');
        start(0);
    });
    $("#btnEndStep2").click(function () {
        $("#step2").addClass('hideMe');
        $("#step3").removeClass('hideMe');
    });
    $("#btnEndStep3").click(function () {
        // Whatever your final validation and form submission requires
        $("#sampleModal").modal("hide");
    });

    function start(al) {
        var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        bar.value = al;
        al++;
        var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 100);
        if (al === 100) {
          bar.value = 100;
          clearTimeout(sim);

          console.log("end");
          $( "#btnEndStep2" ).click();

        }
    }


        </script>
```